# While implementing OLS in a a multiple regression with on dependnt variable and three independent variables Patsy error of numpy is there

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

While implementing OLS in a  a multiple regression with on dependent variable and three independent variables  the following code is being faced

> PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
>      y ~ X1
>      ^

```py
#Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Fitting Multiple Linear Regression to the Training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)   

#OLS for multiple regression
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
X1= add_constant(X)
regressor_OLS = sm.ols(formula = 'y ~ X1', data = X1)
regressor_OLSm = regressor_OLS.fit()
print(regressor_OLSm.summary())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAkty.png)

Answer (score 0):

learners problems i guess

in

regressor_OLS = sm.ols(formula = 'y ~ X1', data = X1)

i should have used fwg

regressor_OLS = sm.ols(formula = 'y ~ X1', data = datset)

sorry for bothering. 
regards
all